# Matlab - Legend does not match my graph

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I am having trouble matching my graph with my axis.  The first two plots work and the second two do not.  I am trying to plot Temperature versus Pressure for two Argo floats and then Salinity versus Pressure. Here is my code:

```
% First Plot
subplot(221);
plot(float1winter.T,float1winter.P,'b');     
hold on;
plot(float1summer.T,float1summer.P,'r');
hold on;
tempAdiff = abs(float1summer.T-float1winter.T)
plot(tempAdiff,float1summer.P,'--k');
hold on;
set(gca,'ydir','reverse');  
title('Argo Float #1901440 Temp Profiles');
legend(['float1winter','float1summer','tempAdiff'],{'11-29-2013','07-01-2013','Temperature Difference'},'location','southwest');
xlabel('Temperature (°C)');
ylabel('Pressure');
shg;



% Second Plot
subplot(222);
plot(float2winter.S,float2winter.P,'m'); 
hold on;
plot(float2summer.S,float2summer.P,'c');
hold on;
set(gca,'ydir','reverse');
title('Argo Float #1901440 Salinity Profiles');
legend(['float2winter','float2summer'],{'11-29-2013','06-02-2013'},'location','southwest');
xlabel('Salinity (psu)');
ylabel('Presure');
shg;



% Third Plot
subplot(223);
% Matrix demensions did not agree bewteen winter and summer profiles.  The summer profile was 71 x 2 and the winter was 70 x 2. I tried "reshape"
% and that didn't work.   So I changed the vector of float3summer.T to
% float3bsummer.T with an array of 70 x 2
float3bsummer.T = float3summer.T(1:70,1:2);
float3bsummer.P = float3summer.P(1:70,1:2);
plot(float3winter.T,float3winter.P,'Linewidth',1,'color','blue'); 
hold on;
plot(float3bsummer.T,float3bsummer.P,'Linewidth',1,'color','red');
hold on;
tempdiff = abs(float3bsummer.T-float3winter.T)
plot(tempdiff,float3bsummer.P,'--k');
hold on;
set(gca,'ydir','reverse');  % this line reverses the y-axis so that depth increases downward
title('Argo Float #1901415 Tempearture Profiles');
hold on;
summerfloat = plot(float3bsummer.T,float3bsummer.P,'r');
legend(['float3winter.T','summerfloat','tempdiff'],{'12-03-2013','07-03-2013','Temp Diff'},'location','southeast');
xlabel('Temperature (°C)');
ylabel('Pressure');
axis ([-1,4,0,2000]);
shg;


% Fourth Plot
subplot(224);
plot(float3winter.S,float3winter.P,'g'); 
% Changed matrix dimensions for Salinity of Summer
float3bsummer.S = float3summer.S(1:70,1:2);
float3bsummer.P = float3summer.P(1:70,1:2);
plot(float3bsummer.S,float3bsummer.P,'.b');
hold on;
set(gca,'ydir','reverse');
title('Argo Float #1901415 Salinity Profiles');
h4 = plot(float3winter.S,float3winter.P,'g');
hold on;
h5 = plot(float3bsummer.S,float3bsummer.P,'.b');
hold on;
legend(['float3winter','float3bsummer.T'],{'12-03-2013','07-03-2013'},'location','southwest');
xlabel('Salinity (psu)');
ylabel('Pressure');
axis ([33.8,34.8,0,2000]);
shg;



% Save File to Desktop
set(gcf,'color','w');
saveas(gcf,'~/Desktop/hw1_figure1.pdf','pdf');![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What doesn't match? Can you show us images of the plots and explain what you expect to see?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you're trying to associate the set of strings for your legend, `{'11-29-2013','07-01-2013','Temperature Difference'}`, with the plots made from the variables `['float1winter','float1summer','tempAdiff']`.

However, this isn't how `legend` works. MATLAB has no way of associating the plot produced by `plot(float1winter.T,float1winter.P,'b');` to the string `float1winter`. If you want to specify which plots go with which legend entries, you need to pass the object handles of the plots to `legend`, which is easiest done by returning the handles when you `plot` originally:

```
h(1) = plot(float1winter.T,float1winter.P,'b');     
hold on;
h(2) = plot(float1summer.T,float1summer.P,'r');
h(3) = plot(tempAdiff,float1summer.P,'--k');
legend(h,{'11-29-2013','07-01-2013','Temperature Difference'});
```

Side note: you only need to call `hold on` once per axis - so once for each `subplot` but not after every `plot` call.

Alternatively, you can not give handles at all; `legend` will assign the text to the plots in the order that they were plotted:

```
legend({'11-29-2013','07-01-2013','Temperature Difference'})
```

Understanding graphics handles allows you a lot more control over plots, especially if you might want to make small adjustments to them.  For example, if I decide that I want the first plot to be green rather than blue, then I can just do:

```
set(h(1),'Color','g');
```

This will change the plot color **and** the legend changes to match automagically.  To see a list of all the properties of an object, use `get` with only the handle. You can `set` more than one property at a time. For example:

```
get(h(1))
set(h(1),'DisplayName','Winter','LineWidth',3,'Marker','x')
```